# Counting the number of HTML attributes on a webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to count a varying number of specific HTML attributes on multiple webpages. I will then use that number to scrape the data I need contained in those `href` attributes.

```
page_a<-"http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all"
fighter_links<-read_html(page_a)%>%
  html_nodes("tr")%>%
  html_nodes("td")%>%
  html_nodes("a")%>%
  html_attr("href")%>%
  .[seq(1,1500,3)]%>%
  na.omit(fighter_links)
```

The purpose of the above code is to read the HTML on that page and extract the links I need. This is only one of 26 webpages I need to scrape, all with a varying number of links I need to scrape from each one.

The problem I have in the above code is that I want to count the number of `href` attributes in those specified nodes. Another solution would be to count the number of `a` or `td` nodes, if that makes a difference. I want to then use that number and insert it in place of the 1500 within `.[seq(1,1500,3)]`.

I know the `seq()` above is incredibly crude; however, that is the only solution I can currently put into practice. I plan on using this program for a long time, and the pages I'm scraping will constantly add new information, so I don't want to hard code anything; hence my wanting to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `length` function to count number of `href` attributes.

```
library(rvest)

page_a<-"http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all"

fighter_links <- read_html(page_a)%>%
                  html_nodes("tr td a")%>%
                 html_attr("href") %>%
                .[seq(1,length(.),3)]%>%
                 #You can also use recycling method
                 #.[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)]%>%
                 na.omit(fighter_links)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I tried using length() before but I guess I didn't do it properly...